# Formatting a command in python subprocess popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to format the following awk command

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{printf "chr%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2-1, $2}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

for use in python subprocess popen. However i am having a hard time formatting it. I have tried solutions suggested in similar answers but none of them worked. I have also tried using raw string literals. Also i would not like to use *shell=True* as this is not recommended

Edit according to comment:
The command i tried was

```
awk_command = """awk -v OFS="\t" '{printf "chr%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2-1, $2}' file1.txt > file2.txt"""
command_execute = Popen(shlex.split(awk_command))
```

However i get the following error upon executing this

```
KeyError: 'printf "chr%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2-1, $2'
```

googling the error suggests this happens when a value is requested for an undefined key but i do not understand its context here

Comment: Welcome to SO! You've shown us what you want, but not what you get, nor the code that generates it. Hard for us to help without the rest of the info.

Comment: Shelling out to awk from python is like pointing a camera at your TV to watch it from another TV. Have you looked at the `re` module?

Comment: you should use raw-string literals: compare: `print(r'"\t"')` vs. `print('"\t"')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The simplest method, especially if you wish to keep the output redirection stuff, is to use `subprocess` with [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#popen-constructor) - then you only need to escape Python special characters. The line, as a whole, will be interpreted by the default shell.

   - *WARNING: do not use this with untrusted input without sanitizing it first!*
2. Alternatively, you can replace the command line with an `argv`-type sequence and feed that to `subprocess` instead. Then, you need to provide stuff as the program would see it:

   - remove all the shell-level escaping
   - remove the output redirection stuff and do the redirection yourself instead

Regarding the specific problems:

- you didn't escape Python special characters in the string so `\t` and `\n` became the literal tab and newline (try to `print awk_command`)
- using `shlex.split` is nothing different from `shell=True` - with an added unreliability since it cannot guarantee if would parse the string the same way your shell would in every case (not to mention the lack of transmutations the shell makes).

  - Specifically, it doesn't know or care about the special meaning of the redirection part:

    ```
    >>> awk_command = """awk -v OFS="\\t" '{printf "chr%s\\t%s\\t%s\\n", $1, $2- 1, $2}' file1.txt > file2.txt"""
    >>> shlex.split(awk_command)
    ['awk','-v','OFS=\\t','{printf "chr%s\\t%s\\t%s\\n", $1, $2-1, $2}','file1.txt','>','file2.txt']
    ```

So, if you wish to use `shell=False`, do construct the argument list yourself.

Comment: I am trying to avoid shell=True. Also according to the later edit i am using shlex.split() which should split it accordingly but somehow i am getting the Keyerror and i am unable to debug its cause here.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the comment. I guess consider my urgency i will go for using shell=True but even with that i am not able to get it to work. The command i used with shell=True is  `Popen("""awk -v OFS="\\t" '{printf 'chr%s\\t%s\\t%s\\n', $1, $2-1, $2}' file1.txt > file2.txt""",shell=True)`  However i guess the part with %s is not getting translated correctly for awk

Comment: You have single quotes inside single quotes.

Comment: Hey Thanks again. Edited that too but still awk throws an error `fatal: division by zero attempted in `%'` I guess it is interpreting it as a modulus sign

Comment: Use some facility to print the cmdline your program is getting to debug this kind of stuff (e.g. `set -o xtrace` for `bash`, process explorer/process monitor for `cmd`).

Comment: FINALLY solved Thanks a lot:). I had been debugging this for the past 2 hrs.

Comment: @Ubutnu_Fedora: you shouldn't spend so much time on such simple issues. To avoid being stuck on simple issues, invest an hour to read [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 1):

`>` is the shell redirection operator. To implement it in Python, use `stdout` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd = r"""awk -v OFS="\t" '{printf "chr%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2-1, $2}'"""
with open('file2.txt', 'wb', 0) as output_file:
    subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(cmd) + ["file1.txt"], stdout=output_file)
```

To avoid starting a separate process, you could implement this particular `awk` command in pure Python.