# How to implement find command to use input from sys.argv in Python

Tags: python, regex, grep, find, associative-array

I have a bunch of search strings in a dictionary that I use to parse information.

```
my_func_dict = {
    'index_one': r'pattern1'
    'index_two': r'pattern2'
    etc
}
```

Then I use the following to capture the path to evaluate and apply my search strings which is working fine.

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    location = sys.argv[1]
else:
    location = raw_input("Enter the path to evaluate...>: ")
```

Then, I iterate the dictionary items to apply the search command:

```
search_cmd = 'grep -h -r'.split()
for name, pattern in my_func_dict.items():
    with open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'a') as output:
        cmd = search_cmd + [pattern, location]
        subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=output)
```

This is working fine for few search patterns and few files to evaluate. But in my case I have many search patterns and apply these to folders with several files which includes several extension types: *.txt, *log, etc, and this is taking ages. I would like to use the `find` option to look only for the specific file type inside in the folder path first and then apply the `grep` more precise in order to obtain the output results much faster.

But following attempt:

```
search_cmd = 'find $location -name "*test.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h -r'.split()
for name, pattern in my_func_dict.items():
    with open('{}.txt'.format(name), 'a') as output:
        cmd = search_cmd + [pattern, location]
        subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=output)
```

Gives me an error:

```
find: |: unknown primary or operator
find: |: unknown primary or operator
find: |: unknown primary or operator
find: |: unknown primary or operator
```

How can I implement my `search_cmd` to avoid this issue?. I need to use `-print0` and `xargs -0` as attributes for `find` because folder name in path has spaces, for example: `/This is the path/for/This Folder`.  Thanks

Comment: This isn't something I am very knowledgable in but shouldn't you get a syntax error on the search_cmd = ... line?

Comment: changed to: `search_cmd = 'find $location -name "*test.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h -r'.split()`, this one gives the `find: |: unknown primary or operator` error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a command in python subprocess popen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985888/formatting-a-command-in-python-subprocess-popen)

Comment: That one has output redirection instead of a pipe but that's no different.

Comment: still not able to make it work after using what suggested in the dup: `search_cmd = shlex.split("""find $location -name "*test.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h -r""")`, still getting following error: `find: |: unknown primary or operator`

Answer (score 0):

You could use subprocess with a full string using `shell=True` with *Popen*. We can also use Python to split the output on newlines.

```
import subprocess

mydict = {'.': 'patte', './': '".atty"'}

results = []
for path, pattern in mydict.items():
    cmd = 'find ' + path + ' -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs fgrep -h --basic-regex ' + pattern
    sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    response = sp.communicate()
    response = [x.decode('utf-8').strip().split('\n') for x in response if x]
    if response:
        response = response[0] 
        results.append(response)
```

results

```
[['pattern1', 'pattern2'], ['pattycakes', 'patty']]
```