# Hex to python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, hex, subprocess, dd

In bash `printf "\x00\x00\xFF\x00" | dd bs=4 seek=$(($y*$width+$x)) of=/dev/fb0`, where `width` is the width in pixel of your monitor, allow you to write a red pixel at the `x`, `y` coordinates on your screen.

I'm using python to retrieve color values of an image and I want to call the previous bash command and put the values I found with python.

When I call the subprocess with:

```
command = 'printf "\x00\x00\xFF\x00" | dd bs=4 seek=276200 of=/dev/fb'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sub.py", line 30, in <module>
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Without the `\x` characters the subprocess works.

```
command = 'printf "test" | dd bs=4 seek=2 of=test.txt'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

I found some interesting links like this one : [Formatting a command in python subprocess popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985888/formatting-a-command-in-python-subprocess-popen)
but I don't really get it. Is it possible to put `\x` characters to a subprocess ? How ? Is there an other way ?

Thank you very much

EDIT:

First of all thank you all for your help.

I found something that do the trick. I don't think that this is the best way to do it but it works.

`printf "\x00\x00\xFF\x00"` in the terminal works normally and print a weird character `�`. But when called in a python subprocess `subprocess.call('printf "\x00\x00\xFF\x00"', shell=True)` it gives an error `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`. When you escape backslash like this `subprocess.call('printf "\\x00\\x00\\xFF\\x00"', shell=True)` it prints `\x00\x00\xFF\x00` and not the weird `�` so this is not exactly the same as the printf directly from the terminal. I tried to escape in a lot of different ways but I didn't get the `�`. I don't know exactly why.

So I made a small `printf.bash` file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf $1
```

And I'm calling the subprocess like this :

```
subprocess.call('./printf.bash "\\x00\\x00\\xFF\\x00"', shell=True)
```

and I get the `�` I want. Strangely this is different than :

```
subprocess.call('printf "\\x00\\x00\\xFF\\x00"', shell=True)
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there some way to pass a string containing binary data to the shell as a command-line argument? If there is,create a `command` string that uses it.

Comment: Why are you using `subprocess` at all? You can open the file and write to it directly from Python. `with open("/dev/fb", "wb") as fb: fb.seek(276200); fb.write('\x00\x00\xff\x00')`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know, it seems interesting, I'm going to test this, what about the `dd` option `bs=4` with fb.seek?

Comment: `fb.seek(276200*4)`

Comment: Thank you that's working... I'm stupid :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the backslash.

```
command = 'printf "\\x00\\x00\\xFF\\x00" | dd bs=4 seek=276200 of=/dev/fb'
```

Edit: In my bash I needed to change your printf for the characters to actually appear:

```
printf "\x000\x000\x0FF\x000"
```

The above might work, if not I'd try adding an extra leading digit and/or escaping the backslash also. edit: Or see the comment below suggesting python's raw string flag. See: [py string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals%22the%20manual%22)

Comment: Yes.  Or, alternatively `command = r'printf "\x00\x00\xFF\x00" | dd bs=4 seek=276200 of=deleteme'`.